# vba - how to copy values from drop down row and compare it with other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have below case

Sheet -**Type** contains Category Section in (A1) and corresponding values in cell B1 (dropdown) which is getting values from D1:D2

[image]

Sheet - **Variables** contain below data

[image]

Sheet - **Price** contains Type Section in Cell A2:A3(dropdown) which is getting values from E1:E2
[image]

**Scenario** : In Price sheet user selects Type value drop down values and when user enters No of Units values  in **Price** sheet , logic need to check what user has selected Category from **Type** sheet and check for the corresponding combination price from Variables and multiply with no of units and display in **Price** sheet-Price column

```
Dim shT as Worksheet, ShP as Worksheet,ShV as Worksheet
Dim strCategory  as String, strType as Long,rowCategory as Long,rowType as Long,Price as Double

set shT = Worksheets("Type")
set shP = Worksheets("Price")
set shV = Worksheets("Variables")

strCategory = ShT.Range("B1").Value
strType = shP.Range("A2").Value


With WorksheetFunction
rowCategory = .Match(strCategory , shV.Range("A1:A5"),0)
rowType = .Match(strType, shV.Range("B" & rowCategory & ":B" & rowCategory +5),0)
rowType = rowType + rowCategory - 1


Price = shV.Range("C" & rowType).Value

End With

For i = 2 To 3
shP.Range("C" & i).value = Price * shP.Range("B" & i)
Next i
```

**Issue:** The above mentioned logic working only for A2 value dropdown in **Price** sheet but not for A3 value.

Is there any way where we can get entire drop down value data and comparing with tabular data in another sheet , issue exits in below logic

```
    strType = shP.Range("A2").Value
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What `Discount` is and where from should it be collected? Basically you should iterate between the elements of 'Price' sheet and redefine `strType` according to the iteration element.

Comment: @FaneDuru - Apologies for confusion , there is no such thing as Discount , updated the question , it is Price

Comment: I started to believe that, but I couldn't be sure... Please, test my answer code, where I introduced the correct `Price`, but kept the `Discount` as being 1. You maybe will also need such a parameter. Or not... Anyhow, like it is it does not influence the result.

Comment: Off topic: do your future self a favor by not allowing your current self to use magic numbers, fixed ranges, hard coded strings, and merged cells.  You will thank yourself for doing it.

Comment: @FaneDuru - Thanks for the help , it is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testBringPrice()
Dim shT As Worksheet, ShP As Worksheet, ShV As Worksheet
Dim strCategory  As String, strType As Long, rowCategory As Long
Dim rowType As Long, Price As Double, i As Long, Discount As Double

Discount = 1 'you should define where from it should be taken
Set shT = Worksheets("Type")
Set ShP = Worksheets("Price")
Set ShV = Worksheets("Variables")

strCategory = shT.Range("B1").value

For i = 2 To 3
    strType = ShP.Range("A" & i).value
    
    With WorksheetFunction
        rowCategory = .Match(strCategory, ShV.Range("A1:A5"), 0)
        rowType = .Match(strType, ShV.Range("B" & rowCategory & ":B" & rowCategory + 5), 0)
        rowType = rowType + rowCategory - 1
                
        Price = ShV.Range("C" & rowType).value
        ShP.Range("C" & i).value = Price * Discount * ShP.Range("B" & i)
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

The above code considers `Discount = 1` (no discount). You must define where from discount value to be taken